# Change the image when clicked, having the mouseenter () method and mouseleave ()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the markup there are icons images.

```js
$('.classSelection').find('.funcName').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
            var imgHover =  ('//dustfade.com/img/' + dataTarget + '_hover_ico.png');
            $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').find('img').attr('src',imgHover);
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            //stuff to do on mouse leave
            var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
            var imgName = ('//dustfade.com/img/' + dataTarget + 'hover_ico.png');
            $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').find('img').attr('src',imgName);
        },
        click: function (e) {
        //stuff to do on mouse leave
        var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
        var imgName = ('//dustfade.com/img/' + dataTarget + '_ico.png');
        $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').find('img').attr('src',imgName);
        },

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="funcName assault_ico" data-target="assault">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" width="75" height="75">
            <p>
                Assault
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="funcName medic_ico" data-target="medic">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/75x75" width="75" height="75">
            <p>
                Medic
            </p>
        </div>
```

With the mouseenter () method, the icon image is replaced with a brighter version.
With the mouseleave () method, the icon image is replaced to original.

When i click(), i need to disable raplacing image to original
I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: So all you want to do is show a different image on hover and then show the original when the mouse leaves, right?

Comment: From what I gather of your question, you just need to check the `src` of the image on the hover and leave functions, and only change the image if the `src` is not the "clicked" image. I'd advise against inserting executable snippets without testing them (these obviously won't work) because they can potentially add unnecessary noise to the question...

Comment: Yes, I want that by clicking the mouseleave method did not change image to original  @Rushikumar

Comment: to clarify: after you click on the image, the image will stay as the "brighter version" from then on, regardless of hover?

Comment: @andi yes, you understand right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you need to go back to the normal state if a different icon is clicked, I think the best thing is to use the click handler to add a class called clicked and then test for that in the other handlers.

```
$('.classSelection').find('.funcName').on({
        mouseenter: function (e) {
            var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
            var imgHover =  ('//dustfade.com/img/' + dataTarget + '_hover_ico.png');
            $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').not('.clicked').find('img').attr('src',imgHover);
        },
        mouseleave: function (e) {
            //stuff to do on mouse leave
            var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
            var imgName = ('//dustfade.com/img/' + dataTarget + 'hover_ico.png');
            $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').not('.clicked').find('img').attr('src',imgName);
        },
        click: function (e) {
            var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
            $('.classSelection').find('.'+ dataTarget + '_ico').trigger('mouseenter').addClass('clicked').siblings().removeClass('clicked').trigger('mouseleave'));
        },

    });
```

Comment: this assumes that all the clickable divs are siblings; if not, adjust the `siblings()` call as needed.

Comment: Big much thank you, Man, do I owe you a beer! You saved my hide today!

Comment: @AntonLevchuk if this solved your question, accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do, is to show a different image on hover and then revert back to the original image, on mouse leave, why go through all this trouble? it is as simple as--

```
<div class="myImages">
    <img src="//image-src-url" class="hoverAction" id="imageName1" width="75" height="75">
    <img src="//image-src-url" class="hoverAction" id="imageName2" width="75" height="75">
    ...
    <img src="//image-src-url" class="hoverAction" id="imageNameX" width="75" height="75">
</div>
```

**Note the following**

- Replace `//image-src-url` with actual image
- All images must have `hoverAction` class
- Replace `imageName` **#** with name of the file
- For simplicity sake, make sure each image has the same extension (e.g. `.png` or `.gif` etc.)

Example:

```
<div class="myImages">
    <img src="//example.com/images/smiley.gif" class="hoverAction" id="smiley" width="75" height="75">
    <img src="//example.com/images/frowny.gif" class="hoverAction" id="frowny" width="75" height="75">
    <img src="//example.com/images/laughy.gif" class="hoverAction" id="laughy" width="75" height="75">
</div>
```

Then, for your JavaScript, add the following to your document `ready`--

```
jQuery(".hoverAction").hover(
    function() {
        var getId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "//image-hover-src-dir"+getId+"_hover.EXT");
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "//image-hover-src-dir"+getId+".EXT");
    }
);
```

**Note the following**

- Replace `//image-hover-src-dir` with location where you have the images stored
- Replace `.EXT` with the appropriate extension of the image
- Make sure you have the corresponding image's `_hover` counter part (example: smiley.gif and smiley_hover.gif)

Example:

```
jQuery(".hoverAction").hover(
    function() {
        var getId = jQuery(this).attr("id");
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "//example.com/images/"+getId+"_hover.gif");
    }, function() {
        jQuery(this).attr("src", "//example.com/images/"+getId+".gif");
    }
);
```

Official jQuery Doc on [Hover Mouse Event](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

#### EDIT

To disable click, try `preventDefault` or better yet, `return false;`

So, modify your code from--

```
click: function (e) {
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
    var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
```

to

```
click: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
    //stuff to do on mouse leave
    var dataTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.target;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, but i need to make when i click dont change to original image. But mouseleave() change it to original. @Rushikumar

Comment: @AntonLevchuk checkout the edited answer --- specifically, `preventDefault()` section

Comment: Oh man, sorry for my english. I need disable mouseleave(), when image is clicked. Becouse when i click on image, mouseleave() change picture to original. What you wrote is suitable for mouseleave()? @Rushikumar

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('.funcName').on('click mouseenter mouseleave', function(e){
        var img = $(this).find('img').attr('src').split('/', 4).join('/').concat('/',$(this).data('target'));
        switch(e.type){
            case 'click' : img += '_hover_ico.png'; break;
            case 'mouseenter' : img += '_hover_ico.png'; break;
            case 'mouseleave' : img += '_ico.png'; break;
        }
        $(this).find('img').attr('src',img);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. Anyway mouseleave() changing image to original. @Anfath Hifans

Comment: which image should be loaded when mouseleave triggered ??

Comment: I have two pictures
image_ico.jpg
image_hover_ico.jpg
When mouseenter() - image_hover_ico.jpg
When mouseleave() image_ico.jpg
And when i  use click() method i need image_hover_ico.jpg
and when i click i need disable mouseleave() method becouse its raplce image to image_ico_.jpg @Anfath Hifans

Comment: @AntonLevchuk test it now

Comment: mouseenter and mouseleave works fine, but when i use click() anyway mouseleave changing image to original (_ico.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

try changing your click function to simply remove the mouseenter and mouseleave handlers.

```
click: function (e) {
    $(e.target).closest('.funcName').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
},
```

Comment: or just `$(e.target).closest('.funcName').off();` if you don't have any other event handlers attached to that element.

Comment: Big much thanks, its working) Now i need to find solution of replace to original when i click others icons xD But you really helped me)  @andi

Comment: if you `off` the event handlers, it's not necessarily trivial to add them back. honestly, the best solution is to do the hover state in CSS, but I'm not sure if you have the access to edit everything.

Comment: can i turn on back this mouseenter mouseleave from other function?

Comment: I have another function that opens a special div when I click on icon.
Can I return mouseenter() mouseleave() through this function?https://jsfiddle.net/4k0wLy4g/1/

Comment: you'd have to recreate it, in that scenario.

Comment: I added a new answer, given this new info.